# Writing on a FIFO with multiple processes

Tags: linux, fifo

I need to make a named pipe with mkfifo. For instance:

```
mkfifo mypipe
```

I'm going to have a systemd service (a simple shell script) that read from the pipe and I will write on the same pipe calling another script (e.g. `write-to-pipe.sh`).

What if I have multiple instances of `write-to-pipe.sh` writing simultaneously on the pipe?
I mean, many users can execute `write-to-pipe.sh`. If two users try to write on the pipe at the same time, is it going to create trouble (like when two users try to write on a regular file (not pipe) and one overwrite the other) or not?

I hope this is not a duplicate, but I couldn't find an answer to this question...

Thanks

Comment: There will be trouble if the whatever's on the other end of pipe expects complete discrete messages.

Comment: @muru, every message written by the shell script will be only one line. At the other end of the pipe I will expect to read every line as a message. Will a single line be written correctly or mixed with other lines from other instances of the script?

Comment: @mugnozzo I have the same problem and with systemd! Did you come up with a solution ? if so, can you please post what worked for you?

Comment: @vyom Unfortunately not. Still don't have a solution.

Comment: @mugnozzo I switched to POSIX MQ, that worked for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a quick test I ran:

```
mkfifo foo
yes "Process 1 reporting" > foo & yes "This is process 2" > foo &
awk '!a[$0]++' < foo
```

And the output I got from awk:

```
Process 1 reporting
Process 1 reportThis is process 2
This is process 2
This is pring
Process 1 reportocess 2
ing
ocess 2
This is prProcess 1 reporting
```

Comment: There is a problem here. I think it is related to _awk_. Since writing into FIFO up to size of PIPE_BUF defined in _limits.h_ must be atomic.

Comment: @snr and what happens when PIPE_BUF % len(sentence) != 0?

Comment: could you elucidate what you try to take to mean by saying  PIPE_BUF % len(sentence) != 0 ??

Comment: I mean a whole number of sentences don't fit in a buffer of size `PIPE_BUF`

Comment: At that case, the one you show as output is possible. But in your example you don't fill the size. Do you?

Comment: By the way, PIPE_BUF % len(sentence) != 0 is wrong formula, what if PIPE_BUF is 1024 and len(sentence) is 97 ?? Does it show that the limit is exceeded?

Answer (score 1):

Use something like `sem` from GNU Parallel:

```
mkfifo myfifo

sem --id myid 'seq 1 10; sleep 1; echo done' > myfifo &
sem --id myid 'seq 2 10; sleep 1; echo done' > myfifo &
sem --id myid 'seq 3 10; sleep 1; echo done' > myfifo &
sem --id myid 'seq 4 10; sleep 1; echo done' > myfifo &

cat myfifo
```