# What prevents stdout/stderr from interleaving?

Tags: shell, osx, stdout, output, stderr

Say I run some processes:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

foo &
bar &
baz &

wait;
```

I run the above script like so:

```
foobarbaz | cat
```

as far as I can tell, when any of the processes write to stdout/stderr, their output never interleaves - each line of stdio seems to be atomic. How does that work? What utility controls how each line is atomic?

Comment: How much data does your commands output? Try making them output a few kilobytes.

Comment: You mean where one of the commands outputs a few kb before a newline?

Comment: No, something like this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/452762/70524

Answer (score 35, accepted):

They do interleave! You only tried short output bursts, which remain unsplit, but in practice it's hard to guarantee that any particular output remains unsplit.

#### Output buffering

It depends how the programs [buffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_buffer) their output. The [stdio library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_file_input/output) that most programs use when they're writing uses buffers to make output more efficient. Instead of outputting data as soon as the program calls a library function to write to a file, the function stores this data in a buffer, and only actually outputs the data once the buffer has filled up. This means that output is done in batches. More precisely, there are three output modes:

- Unbuffered: the data is written immediately, without using a buffer. This can be slow if the program writes its output in small pieces, e.g. character by character. This is the default mode for standard error.
- Fully buffered: the data is only written when the buffer is full. This is the default mode when writing to a pipe or to a regular file, except with stderr.
- Line-buffered: the data is written after each newline, or when the buffer is full. This is the default mode when writing to a terminal, except with stderr.

Programs can reprogram each file to behave differently, and can explicitly flush the buffer. The buffer is flushed automatically when a program closes the file or exits normally.

If all the programs that are writing to the same pipe either use line-buffered mode, or use unbuffered mode and write each line with a single call to an output function, and if the lines are short enough to write in a single chunk, then the output will be an interleaving of whole lines. But if one of the programs uses fully-buffered mode, or if the lines are too long, then you will see mixed lines.

Here is an example where I interleave the output from two programs. I used GNU coreutils on Linux; different versions of these utilities may behave differently.

- `yes aaaa` writes `aaaa` forever in what is essentially equivalent to line-buffered mode. The `yes` utility actually writes multiple lines at a time, but each time it emits output, the output is a whole number of lines.
- `while true; do echo bbbb; done | grep b` writes `bbbb` forever in fully-buffered mode. It uses a buffer size of 8192, and each line is 5 bytes long. Since 5 does not divide 8192, the boundaries between writes are not at a line boundary in general.

Let's pitch them together.

```
$ { yes aaaa & while true; do echo bbbb; done | grep b & } | head -n 999999 | grep -e ab -e ba
bbaaaa
bbbbaaaa
baaaa
bbbaaaa
bbaaaa
bbbaaaa
ab
bbbbaaa
```

As you can see, yes sometimes interrupted grep and vice versa. Only about 0.001% of the lines got interrupted, but it happened. The output is randomized so the number of interruptions will vary, but I saw at least a few interruptions every time. There would be a higher fraction of interrupted lines if the lines were longer, since the likelihood of an interruption increases as the number of lines per buffer decreases.

There are several ways to [adjust output buffering](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25372/turn-off-buffering-in-pipe). The main ones are:

- Turn off buffering in programs that use the stdio library without changing its default settings with the program [`stdbuf -o0`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/stdbuf-invocation.html) found in GNU coreutils and some other systems such as FreeBSD. You can alternatively switch to line buffering with `stdbuf -oL`.
- Switch to line buffering by directing the program's output through a terminal created just for this purpose with [`unbuffer`](http://expect.sourceforge.net/example/unbuffer.man.html). Some programs may behave differently in other ways, for example `grep` uses colors by default if its output is a terminal.
- Configure the program, for example by passing `--line-buffered` to GNU grep.

Let's see the snippet above again, this time with line buffering on both sides.

```
{ stdbuf -oL yes aaaa & while true; do echo bbbb; done | grep --line-buffered b & } | head -n 999999 | grep -e ab -e ba
abbbb
abbbb
abbbb
abbbb
abbbb
abbbb
abbbb
abbbb
abbbb
abbbb
abbbb
abbbb
abbbb
```

So this time yes never interrupted grep, but grep sometimes interrupted yes. I'll come to why later.

#### Pipe interleaving

As long as each program outputs one line at a time, and the lines are short enough, the output lines will be neatly separated. But there's a limit to how long the lines can be for this to work. The pipe itself has a transfer buffer. When a program outputs to a pipe, the data is copied from the writer program to the pipe's transfer buffer, and then later from the pipe's transfer buffer to the reader program. (At least conceptually — the kernel may sometimes optimize this to a single copy.)

If there's more data to copy than fits in the pipe's transfer buffer, then the kernel copies one bufferful at a time. If multiple programs are writing to the same pipe, and the first program that the kernel picks wants to write more than one bufferful, then there's no guarantee that the kernel will pick the same program again the second time. For example, if *P* is the buffer size, `foo` wants to write 2**P* bytes and `bar` wants to write 3 bytes, then one possible interleaving is *P* bytes from `foo`, then 3 bytes from `bar`, and *P* bytes from `foo`.

Coming back to the yes+grep example above, on my system, `yes aaaa` happens to write as many lines as can fit in a 8192-byte buffer in one go. Since there are 5 bytes to write (4 printable characters and the newline), that means it writes 8190 bytes every time. The pipe buffer size is 4096 bytes. It is therefore possible to get 4096 bytes from yes, then some output from grep, and then the rest of the write from yes (8190 - 4096 = 4094 bytes). 4096 bytes leaves room for 819 lines with `aaaa` and a lone `a`. Hence a line with this lone `a` followed by one write from grep, giving a line with `abbbb`.

If you want to see the details of what's going on, then `getconf PIPE_BUF .` will tell you the pipe buffer size on your system, and you can see a complete list of system calls made by each program with

```
strace -s9999 -f -o line_buffered.strace sh -c '{ stdbuf -oL yes aaaa & while true; do echo bbbb; done | grep --line-buffered b & }' | head -n 999999 | grep -e ab -e ba
```

#### How to guarantee clean line interleaving

If the line lengths are smaller than the pipe buffer size, then line buffering guarantees that there won't be any mixed line in the output.

If the line lengths can be larger, there's no way to avoid arbitrary mixing when multiple programs are writing to the same pipe. To ensure separation, you need to make each program write to a different pipe, and use a program to combine the lines. For example [GNU Parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) does this by default.

Comment: interesting, so what might be a good way to ensure that all lines were written to `cat` atomically, such that the cat process receives whole lines from either foo/bar/baz but not half a line from one and half a line from another, etc. Is there something I can do with the bash script?

Comment: sounds this applies to my case also where I had hundreds of files and `awk` was produced two (or more) lines of output for same ID with `find -type f -name 'myfiles*' -print0 | xargs -0 awk '{ seen[$1]= seen[$1] $2} END { for(x in seen) print x, seen[x] }'`  but with `find -type f -name 'myfiles*' -print0 | xargs -0 cat| awk '{ seen[$1]= seen[$1] $2} END { for(x in seen) print x, seen[x] }'` it correctly produced only one line for every IDs.

Comment: To prevent any interleaving, I can do that with in a programming env like Node.js, but with bash/shell, not sure how to do it.

Comment: @AlexanderMills Write to different files, then process the files separately, or concatenate them.

Comment: @AlexanderMills Maybe by running `foo`, `bar`, and `baz` with [`stdbuf`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/stdbuf).

Comment: @JoL can you show an example of that?

Comment: @AlexanderMills Basing myself from Gilles example, I was thinking of something like `{ stdbuf -oL yes aaaa & stdbuf -oL bash -c 'while true; do echo bbbb; done | grep b' & } | head -n 999999 | grep -e ab -e ba` (though it shouldn't make a difference for `yes` since I think it would be line buffered already). After running it, though, I see that results in some variable number of lines of the constant string `abbbb` instead of the empty output I was expecting. I'm not sure why that is.

Comment: @JoL It's due to the pipe buffer filling up. I knew I'd have to write the second part of the story… Done.

Comment: @AlexanderMills I've expanded my answer.

Comment: Gilles, two parts that appear to contradict each other in your answer "Unbuffered: the data is written immediately, without using a buffer" and "echo bbbb; done | grep b writes bbbb forever in unbuffered mode. It uses a buffer size of 8192"

Comment: @iruvar I meant “in fully-buffered mode”. Thanks, fixed.

Comment: can you add a TL;DR to the top? something like the most likely reason they dont interleave?

Comment: @OlegzandrDenman TLDR added: they do interleave. The reason is complicated.

Answer (score 1):

http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#Non-atomic_writes_with_xargs_-P has a looked into this:

> GNU xargs supports running multiple jobs in parallel. -P n where n is
>   the number of jobs to run in parallel.
>
> ```
> seq 100 | xargs -n1 -P10 echo "$a" | grep 5
> seq 100 | xargs -n1 -P10 echo "$a" > myoutput.txt
> ```
>
> This will work fine for many situations but has a deceptive flaw: If
>   $a contains more than ~1000 characters, the echo may not be atomic (it
>   may be split into multiple write() calls), and there is a risk that
>   two lines will be mixed.
>
> ```
> $ perl -e 'print "a"x2000, "\n"' > foo
> $ strace -e write bash -c 'read -r foo < foo; echo "$foo"' >/dev/null
> write(1, "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"..., 1008) = 1008
> write(1, "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"..., 993) = 993
> +++ exited with 0 +++
> ```
>
> Obviously the same issue arises if there are multiple calls to echo or
>   printf:
>
> ```
> slowprint() {
>   printf 'Start-%s ' "$1"
>   sleep "$1"
>   printf '%s-End\n' "$1"
> }
> export -f slowprint
> seq 10 | xargs -n1 -I {} -P4 bash -c "slowprint {}"
> # Compare to no parallelization
> seq 10 | xargs -n1 -I {} bash -c "slowprint {}"
> # Be sure to see the warnings in the next Pitfall!
> ```
>
> Outputs from the parallel jobs are mixed together, because each job
>   consists of two (or more) separate write() calls.
>
> If you need the outputs unmixed, it is therefore recommended to use a
>   tool that guarantees output will be serialized (such as GNU Parallel).

Comment: That section is wrong. `xargs echo` doesn't call the echo bash builtin, but the `echo` utility from `$PATH`. And anyway I can't reproduce that bash echo behaviour with bash 4.4. On Linux, writes to a pipe (not /dev/null) bigger than 4K are not guaranteed to be atomic though.