# What type of buffering does stderr use by default (in linux)?

Tags: linux, stderr

What type of buffering does the standard error stream use by default in Linux?

Answer (score 2):

From the manpage for [stderr(3)](https://linux.die.net/man/3/stderr)

> The stream stderr is unbuffered. The stream stdout is line-buffered when it points to a terminal. Partial lines will not appear until fflush(3) or exit(3) is called, or a newline is printed. This can produce unexpected results, especially with debugging output. ... Note that in case stdin is associated with a terminal, there may also be input buffering in the terminal driver, entirely unrelated to stdio buffering.

See also:
[What prevents stdout/stderr from interleaving?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/476080/what-prevents-stdout-stderr-from-interleaving)?