# Unable to redirect stdout for background terraform process after it received input from named pipe

Tags: pipe, io-redirection, mkfifo, terraform

I have a terraform file:

```
terraform {
  required_version = "1.3.5"
}


locals {
  a = "foo"
  b = "bar"
}
```

in a bash terminal, I can do:

```bash
$ echo "local.a" | terraform console
"foo"
$ echo "local.b" | terraform console
"bar"
```

Now what I'm trying to do is start a process running `terraform console` in the background and feed it commands.

This is what I've tried (following this answer https://serverfault.com/a/815253):

```bash
$ mkfifo /tmp/srv-input
$ tail -f /tmp/srv-input | terraform console >>output.txt 2>&1 &
```

this starts the background process correctly:

```bash
$ ps -ax | grep terraform
6030 pts/0    Sl     0:01 terraform console
```

if I then run:

```bash
$ echo "local.a" > /tmp/srv-input
```

the output file, `output.txt` is empty.

```bash
$ cat output.txt
$
```

If I run:

```bash
$ echo "local.c" > /tmp/srv-input # invalid input
```

the output file, `output.txt` contains the (expected) error:

```
$ cat output.txt
╷
│ Error: Reference to undeclared local value
│
│   on <console-input> line 1:
│   (source code not available)
│
│ A local value with the name "c" has not been declared. Did you mean "a"?
╵

[1]+  Exit 1                  tail -f /tmp/srv-input | terraform console >> output.txt 2>&1
```

---

Why is only the stderr being redirected to the log file, but not stdout?

Comment: Perhaps the two streams are being buffered differently (stderr line-buffered but stdout block-buffered)?

Comment: @steeldriver if that was the case, how can I achieve what I'm after?

Comment: [Potentially relevant answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/476089/108618).