# Logging process loosely coupled from scripts

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, shell, logs

I have a script where all of the logging (output, errors etc) are captured in one single log file each day.
This script can be called more then 10k times a day, with a maximum of 3 calls simultaneously.

The problem I'm facing at the moment is that sometimes the logging is writing through each other in the same logfile when they executed simultaneously.
I was already looking into options like flock and semaphores to solve this, but this could create a queue on execution of the process itself, which is not desired in my case.

So I was wondering if it's possible to do the logging in some other kind of other process, where it only writes in the logfile when no other process is writing? with a result that the logfile is 'clean' and calls towards the script run as it is at the moment, without any delay?

Comment: Related: [What prevents stdout/stderr from interleaving?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/476080/108618)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use the `logger` command which should be on most Linux distros. It is as easy as

```bash
logger "this is my log message"
```

It should, by default, send your logs to `/var/log/syslog`

You can call this in your script, which will then generate a log entry via the standard logging daemons and machinery on your OS which should handle all the concurrency issues you are trying to manage.

Check the `logger` man page for details, there are a lot of options you can tweak including loglevels, etc.

You can also configure your system logger (`syslog` typically) to handle these logs in a special way, including log rotation, compression, filenames, etc, etc...