# Race condition not seen while two scripts write to a same file

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, parallelism

I have two scripts running parallelly and they are echoing to the same file. One script is echoing `+++++++++++++++` to the file while the other script is echoing `===========` to the file.

Below is the first script

```
#!/bin/bash
while [ 1==1 ];
do
    echo "+++++++++++++++" >> log.txt
    # commands
done
```

Below is the second script

```
#!/bin/bash
while [ 1==1 ];
do
    echo "===========" >> log.txt
    # commands
done
```

The log.txt file has around 1400000 lines printed and not a single line has jumbled case like ++== or something like that?

Does Linux prevent this kind of jumbling from happening and if it does then how and why ?

Comment: Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9926616/is-echo-atomic-when-writing-single-lines). In a nutshell, the write will be atomic up to a certain size (PIPE_BUF). After that it might still be atomic, but it is no longer guaranteed to be.

Comment: Also see: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/452762/70524

Comment: @Eduardo Trápani, I read from what you propose, especially https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/write.html "Write requests of {PIPE_BUF} bytes or less shall not be interleaved with data from other processes doing writes on the same **pipe**.".  The specification about PIPE_BUF is specific to pipes (and FIFO... some other parts of the POSIX specification deals with them)... But I havn't found something about PIPE_BUF and regular files.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply, the `echo` command triggers one `write` syscall which is atomic.

Note that `write` doesn’t guarantee to write all bytes it is given, but in this case (few data), it does.

Then in theory `write(fd, buffer, n)` can write less than `n` bytes and return the actual written number of written bytes to enable the program to write bytes at `buffer+n`.

Such a thing may happen with a pipe since the pipe doesn’t have an infinite capacity.

From `write(2)`

> If the  file  was  open(2)ed with O_APPEND, the file offset is first set to the end of the file before writing.  The adjustment of the  file  offset and the write operation are performed as an atomic step.

> According  to POSIX.1, if count is greater than SSIZE_MAX, the result is implementation-defined; see NOTES for the upper limit on Linux.

Comment: So that means the jumbling will never happen ?

Comment: There are no reason for the `write` syscall to write a partial buffer, then all lines won’t be jumbled. But if you try `strace cat /boot/vmlinuz* >/dev/null`, you will find that the file is read and written by blocks: the whole copy is not atomic. With text outputs of a single program, `fprintf` can buffer the text and the whole thing send with few `write` syscall while executing `fflush`.

Comment: The jumbling might happen if your line is longer than PIPE_BUF.

Comment: The `PIPE_BUF` limit is associated with pipes. Here we have a standard file.  But we can have `PIPE_BUF-1` bytes written into a pipe, then afterward, trying to write 2 bytes is not atomic since the pipe is nearly full.

Comment: @FrédéricLoyer, PIPE_BUF is not the size of the pipe, it's the size above which write()s are not guaranteed to be atomic. On Linux, PIPE_BUF is one page size, 4k, much smaller than the default size of a pipe (64k in current versions of Linux IIRC)

Comment: This is not quite the full story: it's relevant that `>>` is being used here, because that causes the files to be opened with `O_APPEND`, which means that each `write` will always (atomically) write to the end of the file. In another scenario, where processes do "open file, move file pointer to end, write" (without `O_APPEND`), you can get the mixing effect (if one process manages to do its `write` between the other process setting the file pointer and writing).

Comment: @psmears And you can get that effect in the shell by using `done > log.txt` instead of `echo ... >> log.txt`. Each process will have its own file offset that doesn't update when the other process writes.

Answer (score 0):

You can try out the limit with this:

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                           

outer() {
    rm log.txt
    inner() {
        a=$(perl -e 'print "'$1'"x'$2'')
        while [ 1==1 ];
        do
            echo $a >> log.txt
            # commands                                                                                                
        done
    }
    export -f inner
    timeout 5 bash -c "inner '-' $1" &
    timeout 5 bash -c "inner '+' $1" &
    wait
    sort -u log.txt
}

replace_repeats() {
    # Replace                                                                                                         
    #   ---                                                                                                           
    # with                                                                                                            
    #  -3                                                                                                             
    perl -pe 's/((.)\2+)/"$2".length$1/e'
}
# This is OK                                                                                                          
outer 10 | replace_repeats
outer 100 | replace_repeats
outer 1000 | replace_repeats
outer 4095 | replace_repeats
# This breaks.                                                                                                        
# It should give:                                                                                                     
# +4096                                                                                                               
# -4096                                                                                                               
outer 4096 | replace_repeats
```

Comment: But only because bash's `echo`, or rather stdio underneath makes more than one `write()` system call for large arguments. Under `stdbuf -o10000`, that won't break for 4096. If you wanted to check for atomicity of the `write()` system calls, you could use zsh's `syswrite` builtin (or perl's syswrite) instead of bash's echo.

Comment: True, and with the above it will be easy to determine where the limit then is.

Comment: No as on Linux at least, the limit, if any, is going to be much larger than the limit on the size of arguments. Shells are also known to be anything but frugal with memory. Here, I'd test by mmapping large files with differing contents so as to be able to call write() with gigabytes large buffers.